# Modulus of integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a continuous function. Let $0 \leq a <b < \infty$. I want to prove that

$$\Big\vert \int_a^b f(x)dx \Big\vert^2 \leq (b-a)^2 \int_a^b \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx$$

Comment: If everything is positive, why are there even absilute values anywhere?

Comment: If we take $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then is this inequality true?

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is false. On RHS you should have $b-a$ instead of $(b-a)^{2}$. For a counterexample take $f(x)=x^{2}$, evaluate the integrals, cancel $(b-a)^{2}$ and then let $b \to a$.

Once you replace $(b-a)^{2}$ by $b-a$ this is just the Cauchy - Schwarz inequality : $|\int f |=|\int (f) (1)| \leq \sqrt {\int |f|^{2}} \sqrt {\int 1^{2}}$. Square both sides.

Comment: According to this we will have $\vert \int_a^b f(x)dx \vert^2 \leq (b-a) \int_a^b \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx$. Will $(b-a)^2$ come?

Comment: @ManuRohilla You have sated the inequality wrongly. Please work through the counterexample I have added to my answer and you will see why there is a mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot...